# to store list from JSON object to java arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, json, arraylist, collections

I'm new to JSON. I need to store the list from JSON object to java arraylist. In JSON object I'm having list of object. which is need to store in Arraylist list = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: If that is what you *need*, then I suggest you choose a JSON library and call it to make it happen.

Answer (score -1):

You can check this example, it specifies exactly what you need

https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-convert-json-array-to-arraylist-in-java

```
    JSONObject jsnobject = new JSONObject(json);  
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsnobject.getJSONArray("languages");  
    ArrayList<Object> listdata = new ArrayList<Object>();  
    if (jsonArray != null) {   
        for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){   
            listdata.add(jsonArray.get(i));  
        }   
    }
```

or java 8 style I recommend to use this one

https://mkyong.com/java/jackson-convert-json-array-string-to-list/

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Person> pp3 = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<Person>>() {});
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29305373)

Comment: changed as suggested